# How to get id of an element whose name is known in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyname

I know the name of HTML element but not id. How to fetch id using name of the element using Javascript. Kindly help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName( 'yourname' );
var id = elements[0].getAttribute( 'id' );
```

[docu @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName)

If you have multiple elements of that name, you will have to run though the array of `elements` and pick the right one. If there is just one, the above code will work.

Comment: Yes, or, simply `elements[0].id`

Comment: +1 particularly for pointing out that a name does not necessarily give a unique id. :)

Answer (score 5):

Sirko's way is correct. Just in case you (or anyone else) are interested, here's the jquery way of doing it:

```
alert($("*[name='foo']").attr('id'));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jKx2s/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

Sirko's way is correct. Just in case you (or anyone else) are interested, here's the weird- ternary-operator-javascript style of doing it:

```
var id = ( typeof (el = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]) != "undefined" ) ? el.getAttribute("id"):"Element does not exist";
```

have fun:-D

EDIT: decreased the readability by putting it all on one line.
Please note the global Namespace pollution which saved one query.This style also prevented a possible error which could occur in Sirkos Code.